# How to link subreport to a main report?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have a main report and a subreport.

[image]

[image]

The main report shows data by period, I need the subreport to show additional information of the same period.
[image]

The parameter is the period. How should that parameter be assigned?

[image]
[image]

Comment: it has been 7-8 years since i have worked on reports. I did create some subreports but do not remember enough to help. Does this article help any: https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=da5f4cca-6435-4400-a814-8d74ae813986

Comment: Thanks for your help, it helped me.

Comment: great. do not forget to post the answer to your own question when you have time